# What's exactly a task in ROS?

Tags: ros, packages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've heard in different places the word task while reading articles related to and documentation about ROS, but, since I'm also quite new to ROS, I'm not sure what it is, and if it's used to indicate different things in different contexts, if it is a general term, or if it's a term only used with one or more specific packages.

In this article [Create your own task](http://wiki.ros.org/continuous_ops/Tutorials/Create%20your%20own%20task), a task is defined as:

> A task is just a bunch of code that gets executed on the robot.

What are examples of this code? Examples of tasks?

At this point it's not clear to me what's the relation between a task and a ROS package. What is the different between a task and a node?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259904/what%27s-exactly-a-task-in-ros?/) by [nbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/29569/nbro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 372 on 2017-04-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think this Task is only in the context of the continuous_ops package; it isn't a concept in the broader ROS ecosystem.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2